# How to add toast style popup to my application?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created an application that runs in the taskbar. When a user clicks the application it pops up etc. What I would like is similar functionality to that in MSN when one of my friends logs in. Apparently this is know as a toast popup?
I basically want something to popup from every 20 minutes toast style fom the application in the taskbar.

My existing application is winforms based written in C# with .net 3.5

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is pretty simple. You just need to set window in off-screen area and animate it's position until it is fully visible. Here is a sample code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Timer timer;
    private int startPosX;
    private int startPosY;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // We want our window to be the top most
        TopMost = true;
        // Pop doesn't need to be shown in task bar
        ShowInTaskbar = false;
        // Create and run timer for animation
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 50;
        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        // Move window out of screen
        startPosX = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - Width;
        startPosY = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height;
        SetDesktopLocation(startPosX, startPosY);
        base.OnLoad(e);
        // Begin animation
        timer.Start();
    }

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Lift window by 5 pixels
        startPosY -= 5; 
        //If window is fully visible stop the timer
        if (startPosY < Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - Height)
            timer.Stop();
        else
           SetDesktopLocation(startPosX, startPosY);
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't account for several factors: 
* Taskbar could be attached to any edge of the screen;  
* User could have a secondary monitor on the right (causing your popup window to pop up nowhere near the taskbar.  
I know this is an old thread, but I wanted to mention it for anyone else looking, as I was.

Comment: Addition to my above comment: Even though it looks like having a secondary screen shouldn't be an issue (because of the Screen.PrimaryScreen usage), Win7 allows non-primary screens to contain the taskbar; and of course, the taskbar location could still be any edge of the screen.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265379/how-to-find-windows-taskbar-location-and-size) for an answer to finding the correct edge for the taskbar.

Answer (score 4):

There's support for notification balloons in Win32 (I'm not a .net programmer), with some useful properties as [old new thing explains](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2005/01/10/349894.aspx).

There's also a system wide semaphor which you should lock to prevent more than one popup from any application appearing at once.

There's a a couple of pages on the toast semaphor on msdn - [the toast semaphor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632289(VS.85).aspx) and in the [broader context of usability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468595.aspx). I also came across some [example code](http://blogs.msdn.com/coding4fun/archive/2006/10/31/912382.aspx) to use the balloon api from C# while looking, but can't vouch for it.

Answer (score -1):

You're moving the form out of the screen to the right, and then raising it. It would never actually raise into the desktop view. X-axis is right and left, Y-axis is up and down. Adding to the X-axis makes it go further right, and adding to the Y-axis makes it go further down.