# How to create form popup from from system tray on windows application (not web) with c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winform application in c#. the main form is usually minimized.
When some event occur, i want to create small popup form that animate above the tray icon with message, click on it, will bring up the main form.

To implement that, i just create simple form ? or there is special system form for that ?
for example, there is the popup message that alert on new mail with msn messenger.

Thanking in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here's a SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461184/toast-style-popup-for-my-application) that covers that very topic. What you're looking for is called a "toast" message.

Answer (score 1):

I've had success using the [NotifyIcon control in WinForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx). Add a NotifyIcon in your form, then call its [ShowBalloonToolTip function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160064.aspx) in your event handler to display your message. Define an event handler for the  [NotifyIcon.DoubleClick event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.doubleclick%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), and popup your main window. Be sure to also hide the balloon message as well.

A decent example of how to do this can be found [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/notifyicon).

The same technique is recommended in WPF, though I'm not a fan about including WinForms components in a WPF app. I've done it before, but it hurts the soul.

Answer (score 1):

The "Toast" popup that msn uses is a custom one, but there is a built in ShowBalloonTip method on notifyicon

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a (borderless) form to do this. You might also want to have a loot at the excellent [Transitions](http://code.google.com/p/dot-net-transitions/) library for fading in/out, sliding around or resizing smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

`form.showdialog()` should work where form is an instance of a form class. 
For some code, you can refer to [WorkingWithWinForms](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/WorkingWithWinForms.aspx).

If you want to display a question or an info, you can use `MessageBox`. here is a [messagebox-show](http://www.dotnetperls.com/messagebox-show).

Answer (score 0):

You should create a normal form.

If you don't want normal window chrome (titlebar & frame), set `FormBorderStyle` to `None`.