# How to make custom toast windows notification in Winforms using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, notifications, toast

I'm trying to display a toast notification after a timer runs out of a given time, the user can close it by clicking anywhere of that notification UI. I can do it by using default notification control but I want to use custom icon based on notification type, with sound. Using default notification control working fine in Windows 10 but Windows 7 notification doesn't look pretty well. So I need a generic implementation so that all Windows OS (7, 8, 10) showing it properly.

Here's a screenshot to better understanding.

[image: SampleNotification]

Comment: Maybe [How to add toast style popup to my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461184/how-to-add-toast-style-popup-to-my-application) and the links in [Win10 toast notifications in winforms](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d09523b3-726a-4d5c-a9b8-6534a21cb9ad/win10-toast-notifications-in-winforms?forum=csharpgeneral)

Comment: I ended up using this for WIndows 7, its genius: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47227665/2964949