# How to display a toast notification from a WinForms project?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, notifications, toast

I have found the following link explaining how to display a Toast notification using C#:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast-desktop

However, on Step 2: Reference the APIs, the Windows.UI and Windows.Data namespaces were not available in the Add Reference wizard.  I learned that it is because my project targets the .NET framework, not .NET core.  I don't want to convert my entire project to .NET core because I rely on certain NuGet packages that might not be compatible.

How can I display Toast notifications from a WinForms app that targets the .NET framework?  I found a nuget wrapper package, but it is for WPF applications.

EDIT:  The notification should persist within Windows Action Center.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461184/how-to-add-toast-style-popup-to-my-application

Comment: @JQSOFT The accepted answer in the question you linked will not persist in the Action Center of Windows 10.

Comment: I can't see any _Action Center of Windows 10_ in your question. Just tried to help.

Comment: I edited my question to clarify.

Comment: It's really simple in Javascript, call `setTimeout()` on a div element. Why are you doing this on the server and installing packages? Just make a div with some styling.

Comment: @Train Originally, my question title started with C# for clarity, but someone edited it out.  Anyways, read my question again and check the tag, this is a WinForms C# application.

Comment: We usually leave tags out of question titles.

Comment: Ah sorry I read it as web forms! My mistake.

Comment: Is showing/hiding a separate window with animations acceptable?

Comment: It might have to be since I am not making a UWP app, although I really want my notifications to be saved within the Windows 10 Action Center.  I am leaving this question open for that reason, otherwise @JQSOFT's initial comment would be enough to answer my question I believe.

Comment: Just found [this](https://github.com/rafallopatka/ToastNotifications) mentioned in a new post and I remembered that you need something like this. Might work for you. Happy new year in advance.

Comment: @JQSOFT Thanks for that, I had seen that github page before, but it's for WPF, not WinForms.  Happy 2020 to you, as well.